# The repository ... does not have a Release file (Maxmind)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, debian, maxmind, mautic

I am following this tutorial: [Maxmind GeoLite2 & GeoIP Database Auto-Update | 2020](https://mauteam.org/mautic/mautic-admins/solved-maxmind-geolite2-database-not-updating/)

I  launched an Ec2 AWS instance with the mautic application (debian 10).

I'm trying to install Geolip Maximind on my instance but without success.

Here are the problems:

When I execute the command `add-apt-repository ppa:maxmind/ppa`
I get the result:

```
More info: https://launchpad.net/~maxmind/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmpxsjdtonq/pubring.gpg' created
gpg: /tmp/tmpxsjdtonq/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
gpg: key DE1997DCDE742AFA: public key "Launchpad PPA for MaxMind" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

When I execute the command `apt update`
I get the result:

```
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://cdn-aws.deb.debian.org/debian buster-backports InRelease
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maxmind/ppa/ubuntu impish InRelease
Err:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maxmind/ppa/ubuntu impish Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/maxmind/ppa/ubuntu impish Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I didn't think it was useful to continue the tutorial because of these errors. I need your precious help to correct them.

Comment: I'm a bit confused why it's looking for "impish" as that is an unreleased Ubuntu release.  Have you tried this on and Ubuntu EC2?  In theory Debian should work with this too but the instructions are aimed at Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

If you are running Debian then you just have to install `geoip-bin` and `geoip-database` and for the updates you install `geoipupdate`. They are all in the standard apt repository.
You do not need to add the maxmind repository.

```
apt install geoip-bin geoip-database geoipupdate
```

Note that depending what you plan to do you may need also other packages for your perl php lua apache lighttp etc ... Since you don't want to tell us what you have in mind, I can't tell you more than that.

There are several packages there ...

```
root@linux:~# apt policy geoipupdate
geoipupdate:
  Installiert:           3.1.1-1
  Installationskandidat: 3.1.1-1
  Versionstabelle:
 *** 3.1.1-1 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster/contrib amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.5.0-1~bpo9+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/contrib amd64 Packages
     2.3.1-1 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch/contrib amd64 Packages
```

The standard apt repositories are :

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ buster main non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates main non-free

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib
deb-src http://ftp.debian.org/debian buster-backports main contrib
```

add them to your /etc/apt/sources.list and then try again

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to install GeoIP for the Mautic application already installed on the instance.
when I execute the command `apt install geoip-bin geoip-database geoipupdate` 


I have this is the error

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package geoipupdate`

I am a non-programmer so I don't really understand what I am doing. My goal is to install GeoIP for the Mautic application.

Comment: I'm also getting `Unable to locate package geoipupdate` on Debian 10.